# Main display black and can not recover it

Tags: display, high-sierra, graphics

I know this is somehow a common issue, however none of the solutions I found worked for me.

I have a macbook pro 15" late 2016 with high sierra. I have my laptop connected to external displays most of the time. Suddenly yesterday when I arrived at home I found that the main display was black, while laptop is running (I can ssh into it, or play with the touch bar...)

I tried every thing I found out there:

- reboot
- reset SMC
- reset non-volatile RAM
- I have done all the items above with both external displays connected and without any peripheral connected (just power).

Since this could be caused by a third party app I will list below the ones that have something to do with displays:

- [Disable Monitor](https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor) (this could be the issue, however I have not used this app during the last 2 months and it was not even installed...).
- [Spectacle](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle)
- flux

The display does not seem to be detected by the graphical card, if I go to `about this mac -> hardware -> Displays` only my external displays are showing there.

**Edit**

I just noted that the apps that were using Touch ID don't ask for it anymore. Could it be because of the SMC/NVRAM reset?

To fix I had to add the fingerprint again

**OS update**

I updated mac osx to 10.13.4 just right now and nothing changed...

What else can I do ?

Comment: Have you disconnected *everything* including the external monitors?

Comment: Yes. I have of course tried all this obvious things.

Comment: one cant make assumptions here. Please add *EVERYTHING* you have done on your question.